# Как вынести background-image за пределы контейнера?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет) У меня есть контейнер куда я помещаю все части страницы (header, main,footer) и там же мой фон (background-image). Мне нужно мой фон вынести за пределы этого div, чтоб он был на всю ширину окна браузера. Как это можно реализовать? Заранее спасибо)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: напишите свой код, будет легше дать ответ

Comment: Делайте `background-image` не для контейнера, а для всего `body`

Comment: @klifort код добавила ниже

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как правило делают обёртку над обёрткой, в самой первой фон а во второй содержимое то есть схема такая :

```
<wrapper>
  <container>
  </container>
</wrapper>
```

И все слова мои в сумме имеют такой вид

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9h3N.jpg);
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

.container {
  width: 980px;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

nav {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
  padding: 0 20px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav a:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.logo {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">G</div>
      <div>
        <a href=""><a href="#">Ссылка1</a></a>
        <a href=""><a href="#">Ссылка2</a></a>
        <a href=""><a href="#">Ссылка3</a></a>
        <a href=""><a href="#">Ссылка4</a></a>
        <a href=""><a href="#">Ссылка5</a></a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Смотреть на весь Экран

Comment: спасибо) Как раз то, что нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Свойство `background-image` работает только в пределах своего блока. Поэтому вынести его за пределы блока нельзя.

Вы можете только добавить блок-обертку и указать `background-image` для него или на имеющийся родительский блок с шириной 100%.

Вы можете сделать главный контейнер на 100% ширину окна, а вложенные - бутстраповские

Еще можете пошаманить с псевдо-элементами :before, :after или доп блоками и свойсвами position: absolute, но это худший вариант, и лучше пересмотреть взгляд на верстку